# Error in using http get request inside a web service (SOAPFault Exception)

Tags: web-services, http, jakarta-ee

I've created a window application which will make an http get request using the following code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);


BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
  (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  result = result + line;
} 


    } catch (IOException ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getCause());
    } 
    return result;.
```

The variable 'result' is a String and I've used these packages

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

This code works perfect. But, I wanted to use this code in a web service. I copied and pasted the same code in the web service, but received the following error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
at $Proxy30.identifyThisSong(Unknown Source)`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)
at com.raghuvenmarathoor.songIdentify.SongIdentify.identifyThisSong(SongIdentify.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:246)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:515)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:155)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:189)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:76)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

I am new to web services. I've googled a lot about this problem, but couldn't find any relevant result(Most of the results were about using http get request to access web services). This is what I am trying to achieve :

1. Access a web service
2. Web service should access information from another website using http get request.
3. return the value retrieved from http get request to my client application.

Any references or alternate ways or suggestions would  be hugely helpful..

Thanks in advance

Raghu

Comment: solved it... The problem was with the libraries, which I didn't add into the project. What confused me was the fact that it worked perfectly in an application but not in a web service!!